# swap first and last column of a 2D array in a text file in java

Tags: java, text-files, multidimensional-array, swap

```
              Input file- 
              5 
              1 2 3 4 5
              2 3 4 5 6
              3 2 1 5 8
```

My work is i should read this input file my.txt and swap its first and last column and output it to another file comp.txt but I am getting a blank file comp.txt

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.*;

// to swap first and last column of 2D array
public class Swap
{
    private static BufferedReader in = null;
    private static int row = 0;
    private static int column = 0;
    private static int[][] matrix = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            // String filepath = args[0];
            int lineNum = 0;
            int row = 0;
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my.txt"));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNum++;
                if (lineNum == 1)
                {
                    column = Integer.parseInt(line);
                }
                else
                {
                    String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++)
                    {
                        if (j == 0) matrix[row][0] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[column]);
                        else matrix[row][j] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[j]);
                    }
                    row++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("The code throws an exception");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null) in.close();
        }

        try
        {
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("comp.txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
                {
                    output.println(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                }
            }
            output.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output I am getting at console-

```
           The code throws an exception
           null
```

Apart from this I am getting a blank comp.txt file

Comment: Why do this in java rather than a more appropriate (scripting) language?

Comment: I am bound to do this in java by my mentor

Comment: So you already have the answer: “The code throws an exception”. You should stop your program at this point and analyze the exception instead of proceeding and writing broken data. I recommend either, using `ex.printStackTrace()` rather than `System.out.println(ex.getMessage());` or simply not catching the exception at all.

Comment: The main problem is that my output file is blank and its not generating the required 2D array

Comment: @user3797489: No, the main problem is that you have an exception *before* starting to write anything and are ignoring it.

Comment: Right. I agree with Holger, you should replace 'ex.getMessage()' with 'ex.printStackTrace()' because that actually tells you by line and by exception type and by error message what the problem is and where.

Comment: If anyone is curious, the error is 

*java.lang.NullPointerException
 at test.example.code.Swap.main(Swap.java:37)*

where line 37 is 
*if (j == 0) matrix[row][0] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[column]);* 

and *tokens* isn't null, but *tokens[column]* doesn't exist

Comment: @Zhuinden I have changed it to tokens[k-1] where k= tokens.length instead of tokens[column] but still it is giving the same error

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do in that line so I still cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I replaced your catch block with

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("The code throws an exception");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I could tell that the error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.example.code.Swap.main(Swap.java:37)
The code throws an exception
null
```

Where the line is

```
                    if (j == 0) matrix[row][0] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[column]);
```

Because you are trying to access the 5th column of `tokens` but it's actually a 5-length array and indices in Java and most C-based languages in general are `zero-indiced` aka the valid indices are from 0 to 4.

Also, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do with this line, so I won't fix it, but that's the error.

EDIT:

Now this is not exactly a legitimate thing to do, but I solved it as I would have done it myself, and I will explain it afterwards. If you mustn't read the code because your "mentor" would be against it, then just read the final lines of this post and solve it on your own.

```
// to swap first and last column of 2D array
public class Swap
{
    private static BufferedReader in = null;
    private static int column = 0;
    private static List<int[]> matrix = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            // String filepath = args[0];
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my.txt"));
            String line = null;

            matrix = new ArrayList<int[]>(); //array length is variable length
                                             //so using a 2D array without knowing the row size is not right
            boolean isFirstLine = true;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (isFirstLine)
                {
                    column = Integer.parseInt(line); //first line determines column length
                    isFirstLine = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    String[] tokens = line.split(" "); // there are no commas in input file so split on spaces instead
                    matrix.add(new int[column]);
                    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
                    {
                        matrix.get(matrix.size() - 1)[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
                        //store the lines of the currently read line in the latest added array of the list
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("The code throws an exception");
            ex.printStackTrace(); //changed exception write out for better info
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        }

        // swapping the elements of first and last in each int array of list
        for(int[] intLines : matrix)
        {
            int temp = intLines[0];
            intLines[0] = intLines[intLines.length-1];
            intLines[intLines.length-1] = temp;
        }

        BufferedWriter output = null;
        try
        {
            output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    "comp.txt")))); //i just prefer bufferedwriters don't mind me
            output.write("" + column); //write the first line that is the array length into file
            output.newLine();
            for (int[] intLines : matrix) //write out each line into file
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < intLines.length; i++)
                {
                    output.write("" + intLines[i]);
                    if (i < (intLines.length - 1))
                    {
                        output.write(" ");
                    }
                }
                output.newLine();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (output != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    output.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I changed the 2D array to a list of arrays, read in the file, fixed that you were splitting along commas instead of spaces, and actually did the swap. You don't necessarily have to take this approach, especially if that is against the rules. Don't even read the code if you mustn't.

Comment: If you're really stuck with it, I'll look into it later though.

Comment: I am stuck at it, by the line if(j==0) matrix[row][0]=Integer.parseInt(tokens[column-1]) i am trying to assign value of last column to first column

Comment: i solved the programming question and added 3 lines on what i changed about your approach and how i fixed things to work

Comment: Yes, I got the solution but my input file's first line is blank and then input file is having column no.,then it is having a blank line again and further the 2D array is given so it is giving- The code throws an exception....java.langNumberFormatException: For input string: ""....... at java.langNumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source).....at        java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)....at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)....at Swapp.main(Swapp.java:26)

Comment: Then you need to change `else` to `else if(!"".equals(line))`

Answer (score 0):

1) Change

```
System.out.println("The code throws an exception");  
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
```

To get detailed description for cause of exception.

```
System.out.println("The code throws an exception");  
ex.printStackTrace();
```

2) From code & exception message it seems like there is a `NullPointerException` as ur array `matrix` is initialized to null and not to array of matching size.

So solution to the exception is[Assuming your core logic is fine] , before assigning any values to `matrix` array, initialize with relevant size i.e with max rows & columns